# If it is possibly good that the world actually exists, is it actually good that the world possibly exists?

Tags: modal-logic, metaethics

**Note**: the question involves some version/vector of the [Barcan formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barcan_formula), albeit with the existential quantifier swapped out for an actuality operator (possibly on terms under propositions rather than just propositions), at least as things stands on the surface. Moreover, my expressions have not been adequately disambiguated over the question of [agential vs. abstract deontic states](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-deontic/#RejeCorePrinSDLOBNECOBRM); there is, to be sure, a possible theological application of the notion that the world "ought to exist," but otherwise we are only reflecting on a sort of "hypothetical-creation thesis," that the possibility of creating a world by virtue of an act of goodness (the goodness itself coming from the act's creativity, or the creativity accompanying some prior goodness) is tantamount to an actual world, created or not, being intrinsically good just because in some abstract context it "could have been" created.

Another formulation might be:

> ◊**OB***E* = **OB**◊*E*

But that sounds really weird (how could it be obligatory for the world's existence to be possible? for whether the world is merely possible is not a contingent matter, originally).<sup>♕</sup> Maybe the image is better construed, then, as:

> ◊**PM***E* = **PM**◊*E*

... where **PM** is at least one flavor of optional/"merely permissible" operations. On the other hand, I assume not only ought-implies-can, but may-implies-can, and so on, so I don't see this image as working.

Perhaps we could try out the weaker(?):

> ◊~**FR***E* = ~**FR**◊*E*

... in which case we can at least say that the existence of the world is not evil, I suppose.

---

<sup>♕</sup>In a world where the iteration of modal operators is everywhere and permanently superfluous, at least, such an obligation seems nonsensical. However, if there is an important, sequential/stackable difference between possibility in particular and possibility in general, or between more generalized or more particularized modality, it might be more evident how such an obligation could obtain: some things are directly/locally (particularly) possible only under other contingent conditions, so we are speaking of some *local* possibility, even though of the "world as a whole," being such that it ought to be given, wherefore there is some more generalized possible will behind it (on the level that makes the more particular possibility, into a possibility as such). Again, this might turn out to be an image of God, or at least of a necessary theistic metanarrative, or however-you'd-like-it.

Comment: For those of us who are not very familiar with deontic logic, can you add an explanation of what it means to say that P is obligatory or permitted in the absence of any reference to a moral agent in P?

Comment: Does the world exist? I am always surprised there are not more solipsists.

Comment: @BillOnne I was surprised to hear Chomsky say he used to think (maybe still does a little?) the world would disappear when he died. Surprised because such a thought never occurred to me until then. https://chomsky.info/20130524/ but also said elsewhere.

Comment: @JKusin Who said? Heh heh.

Comment: If it is possibly good that the world actually exists, but not *necessarily* so, then it is, also possibly, bad. Does it then mean that it is actually bad that the world possibly exists as well? If I remember right Barcan's formula presupposes that all possible worlds have identical object domains, and there were controversies over where quantifiers should range otherwise.